# how to restrict rectangle resizing/moving outside a image in fabricjs?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs and trying to restrict moving/resizing of rectangles outside image.

Here's the fiddle of what I have so far: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/h2zvj3un/1/)

Code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
canvas.setBackgroundImage('http://www.beatnyama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/assets.jpg', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));

this.__canvases.push(canvas);  

canvas.observe("object:moving", function(e){
    var obj = e.target;
    //code goes here to restrict moving/resizing outside image
});
```

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See updated fiddle or run the snippet here.
http://jsfiddle.net/h2zvj3un/2/

Basically you should not use background because you need to know image dimensions.
It is easier ( readibility wise, you can obtain same effect with backgroundImage object ) to use a normal image, not evented, not selectable. and set to back of the canvas.

on image loading save its bounding coordinates.

On object moving calculate object bouding box and check that it is not gonna touch the image box.
If it touch it, restore top and left value of images with the latest known good values.

```js
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  var minX, minY, maxX, maxY;
  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));
  fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.beatnyama.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/assets.jpg', function(img){
  img.evented=false;
  img.selectable=false;
  canvas.add(img);
  minX = img.oCoords.tl.x;
  maxX = img.oCoords.br.x;
  minY = img.oCoords.tl.y;
  maxY = img.oCoords.br.y;
  canvas.sendToBack(img);
  });

function checkmove(e) {
var obj = e.target;
  obj.setCoords();
  var b = obj.getBoundingRect();
  if (!(b.left >= minX && maxX >= b.left + b.width)) {
  obj.left = obj.lastLeft;
  obj.scaleX= obj.lastScaleX
  obj.scaleY= obj.lastScaleY
  } else {
  obj.lastLeft = obj.left;
  obj.lastScaleX = obj.scaleX
  }
  if (!(maxY >= b.top + b.height && b.top >= minY)) {
  obj.top = obj.lastTop;
  obj.scaleX= obj.lastScaleX
  obj.scaleY= obj.lastScaleY
  } else {
  obj.lastTop = obj.top;
  obj.lastScaleY = obj.scaleY
  }
}
function checkscale(e) {
var obj = e.target;
  obj.setCoords();
  var b = obj.getBoundingRect();
  if (!(b.left >= minX && maxX >= b.left + b.width && maxY >= b.top + b.height && b.top >= minY)) {
  obj.left = obj.lastLeft;
  obj.top = obj.lastTop;
  obj.scaleX= obj.lastScaleX
  obj.scaleY= obj.lastScaleY
  } else {
  obj.lastLeft = obj.left;
  obj.lastTop = obj.top;
  obj.lastScaleX = obj.scaleX
  obj.lastScaleY = obj.scaleY      
  }
}
canvas.observe("object:moving", checkmove);
canvas.observe("object:scaling", checkscale);
```

```html
<script src="http://fabricjs.com/lib/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id='canvas' width="550" height="550" style="border:#000 1px solid;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Moving is restricted now but resizing is still not working . Please have a look.

Comment: i modified it, but cmon put a little bit of effort, it was a really easy extension

Comment: Thank you for a quick response . Now if I drag to resize on left or right ,it works perfectly, whereas all other directions are resizing outside the image

Comment: Moving as well as resizing are not working on Y axis . I have modified the fiddle to make it work as a extension to your logic, but now when I resize the shape towards the y-axis (start/end) the size increases. Can you look onto that?  Here's the updated code http://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/h2zvj3un/5/.

Comment: yes i did too fast and i was too optimistic. Consider if you want better movement and scaling effect you have to do 2 separate functions, not a single one as i did.

Comment: Yes I have done but don't know why It increases the size of circle if I drag towards the corners on y axis . Can you have a look on  jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/h2zvj3un/5 , I will accept this answer after that